# Reload jQuery Carousel on window resize to change orientation from vertical to horisontal

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, window, carousel

I'm creating a gallery for a responsive lay-out - I am using [jQuery Riding Carousels](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) for the thumbnails.

When the window is re-sized to smaller than 1024px, the orientation of the carousel needs to change from vertical to horizontal ...

I'm doing it like this at present:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
    vertical: $(window).width() > 1008,
    scroll: 3,
  });
});
</script>
```

... the JS simply hooks up a class, but it doesn't do so if you re-size the browser window by dragging it - you need to refresh the page.

Is there a way to destroy the script and re-initialize it on the fly?

Comment: Solution Added with working example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check Working exmpale: http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqpba/1/Jcarousel%20vertical%20on%20resize
Tested in all browsers and works perfectly fine. bounty is mine :) 
In the example i have give threshold widht 350 you can test it by resizing the result pane and as soon as you start havin horizontal scroll bar it will converted to vertical.

1 possible issue depending on your requirement is if you ahve any handlers on images they will be gone after changing display way. the solution for it is wrap your #mycarousel  in a div and use Jquery delegate to handle events on the wrapper so no issue with events also.
Let me know if you come under this situation.

Following code is exactly as per your need.

When the window is re-sized to smaller than 1024px, the orientation of the carousel needs to change from vertical to horizontal .

which is revers form the example as  for me it makes more sense if width is less make it vertical.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var widthCheck = 1008;
    var resizeTimer = null,
        verticalFlg = $(window).width() > widthCheck;
    var obj = jQuery('#mycarousel').clone();
    $('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        vertical: verticalFlg,
        scroll: 2
    });
    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        resizeTimer && clearTimeout(resizeTimer); // Cleraring old timer to avoid unwanted resize calls.
        resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            var flg = ($(window).width() > widthCheck);
            if (verticalFlg != flg) {
                verticalFlg = flg;
                $('#mycarousel').closest(".jcarousel-skin-tango").replaceWith($(obj).clone());
                $('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
                    vertical: verticalFlg,
                    scroll: 2
                });
            }
        }, 200);
    });
})
```

Comment: Almost there - actually, it works 100%, but I'm getting jQuery errors (not affecting the functionality though).


_jCarousel: No width/height set for items. This will cause an infinite loop. Aborting..._

... I'm also not seeing this in your example, but I'm not using any of the default themes (which may make provision for the missing values elsewhere).


Either way - nice job ... have some bounty :)

Comment: is the container become hidden any any point of time during resizing. if you can provide some working link or some more code i can help in debugging.

Comment: Thanks ... it's on local only for a project that I can't make public at present. Everything works fine, despite the errors in console that indicates that the CSS isn't loaded (hence the JS can't calculate the size of the clipping container), but the styles ARE actually loaded and everything displays/functions just fine. Thanks again for the help, I'll check in on you sometime once I have this staged and can allow you access. _Cheers_

Answer (score 1):

Or you can look at the source.  I'm guessing you are using version 0.2

Looking at the source
https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel/blob/0.2/lib/jquery.jcarousel.js
we can see that there are two lines (80 and 81) which are only done in object init.  Those lines are

```
this.wh = !this.options.vertical ? 'width' : 'height';
this.lt = !this.options.vertical ? (this.options.rtl ? 'right' : 'left') : 'top';
```

also this line at 149

```
if (!this.options.vertical && this.options.rtl) {
  this.container.addClass('jcarousel-direction-rtl').attr('dir', 'rtl');
}
```

It might be if you add those to the callback you will get better results.

You could also try version 0.3 of the plugin.

---

Prior answer:

Can't test it myself right now, but try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
    vertical: $(window).width() > 1008,
    scroll: 3,
    reloadCallback: function () {
        this.options.vertical = $(window).width() > 1008;
    },
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: No go - I'm beginning to think that the only way to achieve this is to just reload the page when a user re-sizes the browser window to less than 1024 wide, and forget about re-loading just the script.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      var sizeCheck = function() {
        return $(window).outerWidth() >= 1024
      }
      jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        vertical: sizeCheck(),
        scroll: 3,
      });
      var jCarousel = jQuery('#mycarousel').data('jcarousel');
      window.onresize = function() {
        jCarousel.options.vertical = sizeCheck(); // maybe you have to access the option through jCarousel.plugin.options.vertical
        jCarousel.reset();
      }
    });
    </script>
```

Maybe this works.

Comment: Sorry, not working - it actually removes the thumbnails from the carousel as soon as you re-size. Once the viewport shrinks to less than 1024, I get an error stating that width & height is not set (assuming because the -vertical class hook isn't updated).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested the following code, but I am fairly sure the following code should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var carousel;
    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        if(carousel !== undefined) carousel.destroy();
        carousel = jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
            vertical: $(window).width() > 1008,
            scroll: 3,
        });
    });
</script>
```

or even better something along the lines of:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var carousel;
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        carousel = jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
            vertical: $(window).width() > 1008,
            scroll: 3,
        });
    });
    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        //NOT SURE WHICH OF THE BELOW LINES WOULD WORK, try both and check which works
        carousel.options.vertical = $(window).width() > 1008;
        carousel.vertical = $(window).width() > 1008;
        carousel.reload();
    });
</script>
```

If it does not, you should add a `console.log(carousel)` to your code and check out what the prototype is of the outputted value (check F12). There should be something along the lines of destroy (or alternatively check `console.log($.jcarousel())`).